# A more efficient way of creating an NxM array in Python

Tags: numpy, performance, for-loop, matrix

In Python, I need to create an NxM matrix in which the ij entry has value of i^2 + j^2.

I'm currently constructing it using two `for` loops, but the array is quite big and the computation time  is long and I need to perform it several times. Is there a more efficient way of constructing such matrix using maybe Numpy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcasting in numpy. You may refer to the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). For example,

```
import numpy as np
N = 3; M = 4   #whatever values you'd like

a = (np.arange(N)**2).reshape((-1,1))   #make it to column vector
b = np.arange(M)**2

print(a+b)  #broadcasting applied
```

Instead of using `np.arange()`, you can use `np.array([...some array...])` for customizing it.